# Permutations of letters under some conditions

Tags: permutations

Let $W(p,q,r,s)$ be the number of permutations of the letters which satisfy the following conditions :

**Condition 1** : The letters are consist of $P,Q,R,S$.

**Condition 2** : The number of letter $P,Q,R,S$ is $p,q,r,s$ respectively.

**Condition 3** : Any two adjacent letters are different from each other.

**Condition 4** : The first letter is $P$, and the last letter is **not** $P$.

Then, here is my question.

> **Question** : Can we get a closed-form expression of $W(p,q,r,s)$ for $p\ge 2$?

**Motivation** : I've just got the following closed-form expression of $W(1,q,r,s)$ :

$W(1,q,r,s)=$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{q+1}\binom{r-1}{k-1}\left\{\binom{q-1}{k}\binom{2k}{q-1+r-s}+2\binom{q}{k}\binom{2k}{q+r-s}+\binom{q+1}{k}\binom{2k}{q+1+r-s}\right\}$$

However, I'm facing difficulty for the $p\ge 2$ cases. Can anyone help?

*Update* : I crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150327/permutations-of-letters-under-some-conditions).

Comment: Any stronger motivation you can give to us? Why are you interested in $W$?

Comment: @EricStucky: No special reason. I just changed some 'usual' problems because of my interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer just to inform that the question has received an answer by Ilya Bogdanov on MO.